# Node.js https Cert Expiration

Tags: node.js, iis, ssl

I'm looking at setting up Node over https, which references the pfx certificate file.  What happens when the certificate expires?  I believe for IIS, a new SSL cert is generated and installed.  Does this mean the new certificate would also need to be copied/referenced for Node?

If so, is there any way to seamlessly set up SSL with Node and that would continue to work even after cert expiration, to alleviate this?  Some kind of reference to IIS itself perhaps?  Our sysadmins are familiar with updating IIS, but I have a feeling all my node code will start breaking in 2016 (two years from now) when the cert expires, and I may not be around to help.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with IIS  or Node, but a certificate will not automatically renew itself. Renewing means that a new certificate request with a new lifetime has to be generated and that the issuer has to sign this certificate request. And finally the newly created certificate has to put on the server to replace the old one. It might be that IIS automates some part of this (e.g. creating a new certificate request based on the old certificate), but I doubt that it automates the process of sending the certificate request to the CA and get the newly signed certificate back. Actually, from looking at the documentation of some CAs it looks like there is lots of manual work still involved.

Comment: Hoping there is some way for Node to be configured to use SSL, but only need to reference a pointer or something that's not impacted by the cert renewal process.

Comment: There are several information out there how to setup Node with SSL, which can be easily found with a search engine. It effectively boils down to the same setup as with other servers, e.g. configuring where your certificate, key and CA chain are in the file system. The only way to share this setup with another server is if both use the same file format and path (I don't know if IIS uses a path at all or saves them somewhere in a database or similar) or if you write a script to synchronize these data between servers.